# Табы на CSS + JS, с возможностью действия яндекса

Tags: jquery, css, javascript

Есть кусок меню из подвала сайта такого кода:

```
 <footer class="pagefooter">
  <dl class="nav_footer">
    <dt><a href="$tablink"><span>tabtext</span></a></dt>
    <dd>
      tab content
    </dd>
    <dt><a href="$tablink2"><span>tabtext2</span></a></dt>
    <dd>
        tab content2
    </dd>
  </dl>
</footer>
```

На сайте - джейквери есть.

Хочется сделать так, чтобы было как на яндексе, т.е. при клике на заголовок табы, он в *dt* - открывалось содержимое табы, оно в *dd*, при двойном клике - переход на страницу по ссылке.

Comment: никто совсем не знает, как сделать?

Comment: а в чем проблема то ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/CXVzW/

Comment: а это тут причем?

Comment: при том то единственная проблема - прехват dblclick . все остальное вообще тривиально. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/CXVzW/1/

Comment: отлично, вы видели вопрос? у меня вопрос про вкладки(табы), а не исчезновение объекта по клику.

Comment: и в чем вопрос ? что именно у вас не получается ? [табы](https://www.google.com/search?q=tabs+jquery) ? [перехват клика](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/CXVzW/1/) ? [всё вместе](http://careers.hashcode.ru/) ?